# How to fix renderflex error in ListTile in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart

I have a List which has a ListTile as defined below. The ListTile has a trailing parameter that doesn't seem to fit and throws a renderflex error.
This is what my output looks like:

[image]

This is the code of the Listile:

```
 return ListTile(
      onTap: onTap,
      isThreeLine: false,
      trailing: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          RichText(
            maxLines: 2,
            
            text: TextSpan(
              text: 'Tommand',
              style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                  textStyle: khomeStyle.copyWith(
                      fontSize: 12.3,
                      color: kDarkBlue,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      title: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              right: getValueForScreenType<double>(
                context: context,
                mobile: 10,
                tablet: 25,
              ),
              top: getValueForScreenType<double>(
                context: context,
                mobile: 5,
                tablet: 10,
              ),
              bottom: getValueForScreenType<double>(
                context: context,
                mobile: 5,
                tablet: 10,
              ),
            ),
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
              child: Container(
                height: getValueForScreenType<double>(
                  context: context,
                  mobile: 60,
                  tablet: 90,
                ),
                width: getValueForScreenType<double>(
                  context: context,
                  mobile: 60,
                  tablet: 90,
                ),
                child: Image.network(tasks['url'].toString()),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text(
                'Hello',
                style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                  wordSpacing: 0,
                  letterSpacing: 0,
                  textStyle: khomeStyle.copyWith(
                      fontSize: getValueForScreenType<double>(
                        context: context,
                        mobile: 15,
                        tablet: 27,
                      ),
                      color: kDarkBlue,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.62,
                child: RichText(
                  maxLines: 2,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  text: TextSpan(
                    text: 'Hello my name is Tom which is short for Tommand',
                    style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                      textStyle: khomeStyle.copyWith(
                          fontSize: getValueForScreenType<double>(
                              context: context, mobile: 12, tablet: 20),
                          color: kGrey,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        
        ],
      ),
    );
```

I have tried alot of things but i haven't been able to get rid of this error. I tried reducing the fontsize but it didn't really help.

Comment: Wrap the `Column` child of the `Row` in an `Expanded`.

Comment: That is not how you use a ListTile. Why would you have Rows and Columns in your ListTile? Take a look at this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l8dj0yPBvgQ . You could achieve the same thing without unnecessary rows and columns

Comment: @Uni I was using ListTIle as given in the documentation. However there is not much flexibility when you use the predefined parameters. Also i wanted to integrate support for multiple device sizes which was just not possible unitl I customised the ListTile

Comment: If you really want to use rows and columns its ok but ListTile is best used when you follow the Material design principles. You could do implement the same thing with a card and one row.